# Bottom sheet does not close on bottomSheetRef.current.close()

Tags: react-native

I have the following component:

```
import {
  Alert,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  View,
  Modal,
  Pressable,
  Switch,
  ScrollView,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";
import { Listing } from "../../shared/types/listing";
import ListingStack from "../../components/listings/listingsStack";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef, useMemo, useCallback } from "react";
import SkeletonListingStack from "../../components/listings/skeletonListingsStack";
import { getListings } from "../../services/api/listings";
import BottomSheet from "@gorhom/bottom-sheet";
import tw from "tailwind-react-native-classnames";
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import { AdjustmentsHorizontalIcon } from "react-native-heroicons/outline";

const ListingScreen = () => {
  const [listings, setListings] = useState<Listing[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const bottomSheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);

  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ["90%"], []);

  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    price_from: null,
    price_to: null,
    listing_type: null,
    has_wifi: false,
    has_closed_living_room: false,
    has_pool: false,
    has_air_conditioner: false,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      getListings()
        .then((listingsData) => setListings(listingsData))
        .catch((err) => Alert.alert("server error"))
        .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
    }, 500);
  });

  function showFilters() {
    bottomSheetRef.current?.expand();
  }

  async function applyFilters() {
    setIsLoading(true);
    bottomSheetRef.current?.close();

    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 500)
  }

  const filtersFooter = () => {
    return (
      <View className="items-center bg-red-transparent">
        <Pressable
          className="w-auto h-auto mb-6 bg-cyan-500 rounded-lg py-3 px-6 flex items-center"
          onPress={applyFilters}
        >
          <Text className="text-white font-semibold ">Apply filters</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{
          headerRight: () => (
            <View className="mr-2">
              <Pressable onPress={showFilters}>
                <AdjustmentsHorizontalIcon />
              </Pressable>
            </View>
          ),
        }}
      />
      <View>
        {isLoading? <SkeletonListingStack /> : <ListingStack listings={listings} />}

        <BottomSheet
          ref={bottomSheetRef}
          index={-1}
          snapPoints={snapPoints}
          enablePanDownToClose={true}
          footerComponent={filtersFooter}
        >
          <View className="flex flex-1">
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={tw` px-2 items-center`}>
              <Text className="text-lg text-slate-700 font-semibold mt-4">
                Filters
              </Text>
              <View className="w-full">
                <View className="mt-4 w-full flex flex-row justify-between items-center">
                  <View className="w-1/2 pr-2">
                    <View className="w-full">
                      <Text className="text-md">Min price (IDR)</Text>
                      <TextInput
                        className="p-2 mt-2 rounded border w-full border-gray-100 bg-gray-50"
                        value={filters.price_from}
                        keyboardType="numeric"
                        onChangeText={(e) => {
                          setFilters({
                            ...filters,
                            price_from: parseFloat(e),
                          });
                        }}
                      />
                    </View>
                  </View>
                  <View className="w-1/2 pl-2">
                    <View className="w-full">
                      <Text className="text-md">Max price (IDR)</Text>
                      <TextInput
                        className="p-2 mt-2 rounded border w-full border-gray-100 bg-gray-50"
                        value={filters.price_to}
                        keyboardType="numeric"
                        onChangeText={(e) => {
                          setFilters({
                            ...filters,
                            price_to: parseFloat(e),
                          });
                        }}
                      />
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </View>
                <View className="mt-4 w-full flex flex-row justify-between items-center">
                  <Text className="text-md">Air conditioner</Text>
                  <Switch
                    value={filters.has_air_conditioner}
                    onChange={() =>
                      setFilters({
                        ...filters,
                        has_air_conditioner: !filters.has_air_conditioner,
                      })
                    }
                  />
                </View>
                <View className="mt-4 w-full flex flex-row justify-between items-center">
                  <Text className="text-md">Closed living room</Text>
                  <Switch
                    value={filters.has_closed_living_room}
                    onChange={() =>
                      setFilters({
                        ...filters,
                        has_closed_living_room: !filters.has_closed_living_room,
                      })
                    }
                  />
                </View>
                <View className="mt-4 w-full flex flex-row justify-between items-center">
                  <Text className="text-md">With pool</Text>
                  <Switch
                    value={filters.has_pool}
                    onChange={() =>
                      setFilters({
                        ...filters,
                        has_pool: !filters.has_pool,
                      })
                    }
                  />
                </View>
                <View className="mt-4 w-full flex flex-row justify-between items-center">
                  <Text className="text-md">With WiFi</Text>
                  <Switch
                    value={filters.has_wifi}
                    onChange={() =>
                      setFilters({
                        ...filters,
                        has_wifi: !filters.has_wifi,
                      })
                    }
                  />
                </View>
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
        </BottomSheet>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default ListingScreen;
```

There is a BottomSheet component that should be closed when `applyFilters()` method is called. But what happens is isLoading state is changing and BottomSheet still open.

If the `applyFilters()` method contains only `bottomSheetRef.current?.close()` call then it works well. But if I change the state of `isLoading` inside of `applyFilters()` then it works strange for me. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';


const applyFilters = useCallback(() => {
    bottomSheetRef.current?.close();
}, []);
```

Details are [Here](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet/blob/master/example/app/src/screens/basic/BasicExamples.tsx)